# Rails - How to have different languages for different input fields in the same form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form with multiple input fields, and I need the option to specify the input language for a particular input field (a text_area) in the form to Arabic (by default), while the remaining form inputs default to English. The reason I need this is because of the different formatting between arabic and english, (in Arabic text it is written from right to left). once the input is saved, I also need to have it displayed with correct formatting on the show page.

My form:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@admin_circular, :html => { :multipart => true }, layout: :horizontal) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">

    <%= f.text_field :number %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">

    <%= f.text_area :subject %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">

    <%= f.date_select :date_issued %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.file_field(:report) %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

How can I do this?

**P.S:** its not absolutely crucial that the input defaults to arabic, but I would like to have the option to type in arabic with correct formatting in that particular feild.

Comment: Did you tried with ajax reload div with new language?

Comment: To be honest I am not familiar with ajax, I am quite new to coding and haven't delved into ajax yet. would you be able to provide a brief explanation or point me to a place where I could learn to do this? Thanks!

Comment: its not absolutely crucial that the input defaults to arabic, but I would like to have the option to type in arabic with correct formatting in that particular feild.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should look into is the [l18n API using locales](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setup-the-rails-application-for-internationalization). Basically you'll be able to use this built in rails API to achieve the functionality you desire.